# Firebase - Where is My Account Secret in the New Console?

Tags: firebase, firebase-console

I just updated my projects to the new Google Apps / Firebase console.

Where do I find the secret associated with my account in the new console?

Answer (score 146, accepted):

1. click on the settings/cog wheel icon next to your project name at the top of the [new Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/)
2. Click <kbd>Project settings</kbd>
3. Click on the <kbd>Service Accounts</kbd> tab
4. Click on <kbd>Database Secrets</kbd>
5. Hover over the non-displayed secret and click <kbd>Show</kbd>

Comment: great, thank you, it was not obvious. However keep in mind – database secrets are deprecated and should not be used (details on https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup)

Comment: It's deprecated, but what other value to use for calling the REST endpoints is unclear.

Comment: "Database secrets are currently deprecated and use a legacy Firebase token generator. Update your source code with the Firebase Admin SDK."

Answer (score 11):

[image]I have added a picture with steps on how to reach this step. You may find this useful https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8jRJ.jpg

Answer (score 5):

To see a full list of all the credentials associated with your firebase app you would have to go to

[Google Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials)

On the menu tab select your firebase project from the dropdown menu.

On the Credentials tab you will find all your keys both **API keys** and **OAuth 2.0 client IDs** for both browser and server authentications.

Comment: So if we want a separate app to get data from the firebase app, we specify the URL here?

Answer (score 1):

First you have to create a Realtime Database then you can find your secret key under Project settings --> Service accounts--> Database secrets

Comment: Data secrets are deprecated